# Websphere Liberty 8.5: Setting Java classpath

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I am running Websphere Liberty 8.5. My application reads some files from the file system that are obtained via the Java CLASSPATH and I can't seem to find a way to append a directory from the file system to the CLASSPATH Liberty reads from. I've tried manually changing JAVA_CMD and JAVA_DEBUG but none of them take.

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Could you post a fragment of code that shows which way you are reading the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the JVM application classpath (normally specified via the -classpath JVM argument or the CLASSPATH environment variable). I would recommend using a [<library>](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_shared_libs.html) to give your applications visibility to the resources.  If you need a directory, you should use `<library><folder dir="..."/></library>`.

(As an aside, modifying the wlp/bin scripts or setting those "internal" script variables is not a supported external.)

Comment: This is the consolidated answer from wasdev.net: https://www.ibmdw.net/answers/questions/13384/websphere-liberty-85-setting-java-classpath/

Answer (score 2):

ANOTHER WARNING! It only reads JAR files! I had the same issue with endless frustration. Even if you use the `<library><folder dir="..."/></library>` method above, it will only read **jar** files from the classpath. I had a bunch of properties files that I read from the classpath in JBOSS, WebSphere (full), and Glassfish, but the same method doesn't work for Websphere Liberty. What I ended up doing is the above, and putting my properties files all in a .jar file. Very annoying but a work-around, in case you need to read non-jar files.

Comment: I believe it used to be the case that `<library>` could only read .jar files and not resources from directories, but it should not be true in the latest fixpack. If you're still seeing problems, I would encourage you to open a PMR with IBM so the problem can be resolved.