# logback.xml file at classpath location is not picked up on was liberty profile server

Tags: logback, websphere-liberty

I am using was liberty profile as my application server and logback as logger. I have placed  my logback.xml at classpath location as suggested by logback documentation but it is not getting recognized. when I create a jar of logback.xml and place at the same path it gets recognized. But the issue with jar is I cann't modify the logging level at runtime.

I have read at the below link, reading the conf file is not possible in liberty. I am not sure if it is the case. If it's the case then it's a bigger issue.
[Websphere Liberty 8.5: Setting Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658494/websphere-liberty-8-5-setting-java-classpath)

Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

logback.xml should be in the resources folder. I suggest you to add to the runner of your container to add this

`-Dlogback.configurationFile=/myConFolder/logback.xml`

Comment: Thanks Ahiel, I first moved the logback.xml to resources directory to see if this is picked automatically but that didn't happened. Then I added the path of logback.xml in jvm.options file and it worked.

Comment: I did some debugging to check why it doesn't find the file in src/main/resources/ and I couldn't find the cause either. Very annoying. When I manually copy logback-test.xml to the classes/ directory then it works. And it works in JUnit but not a Java Application.