# Loading properties file WebSphere Liberty

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a simple application that uses Spring to load a properties file from the classpath. When deploying this application to WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5 it results in `FileNotFoundException`.

> nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/myprops.properties]

Here is my spring @Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
@PropertySource("classpath:/myprops.properties")
public class AppConfigDev extends AppConfig {
  ...
}
```

I am wondering where in the Liberty directory structure should my properties file reside?

Comment: In WEB-INF/classes or in a jar in WEB-INF/lib should work. Where is the file?

Comment: I've since changed this to use "file:myprops.properties" as I do not want to source the classpath. In Liberty I am curious what is the current path when sourcing a file this way using relative path.

Comment: The current working directory will be the server output dir.

Answer (score 0):

The use of prefix `classpath:` in your annotation signifies that the given property file would be picked up from WebSphere's, well, `classpath`, via a `ClassLoader.getResources(...)` call.

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-classpath-wildcards

You will need to create a jar of all your properties files for Websphere Liberty to be able to load them.

Ref: 
1. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/13384/websphere-liberty-8-5-setting-java-classpath.html 
2. [Websphere Liberty 8.5: Setting Java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658494/websphere-liberty-8-5-setting-java-classpath)

Comment: Preferably I do not want to create and package the properties in a jar file. Instead I want to source it from the file system. In WAS ND 8.5 classpath works and load the properties file from the "properties" directory within the profile. For WebSphere Liberty it fails, as described above. I've since changed this to "file:myprops.properties" and I still get FileNotFound error. Preferably I want to use a relative path and not a full path for sourcing the properties files.

Comment: @sleepyj See the first link: use `<library><folder dir="..."/></library>`.  There are various variables described in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_dirs.html that you can use to avoid absolute paths in your configuration; e.g., `${server.config.dir}/properties` or `${shared.config.dir}/properties` might be good choices for your environment.

Comment: Ah yes just noticed that after posting. Thanks. I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name/directory of your files in a file named `jvm.options` and put it in your `${server.config.dir}/jvm.options`

Specific example :

In the file: `${server.config.dir}/jvm.options`

Add the following line: `-DAPP_ENV=PROD`

Access the value with: `System.getProperty("APP_ENV"); -> PROD`